# How to send request to backend SSL url that converts from HTTP:7000 to HTTPS:7001 after verification running on weblogic using Angular front end app

Tags: java, angular, angularjs, ssl, weblogic

I have a backend application that is running on weblogic server. It is running on http://localhost:7000. This application has to be called with http://localhost:7000 then after verification it checks if the application schema is on https or not. If its not then it asks you to redirect to https://localhost:7001. The HTTPS configuration is enabled on weblogic server

[WEBLOGIC SSL CONFIGURATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNNoo.png)

So far everything running on same domain meaning the application is full fledge with java backend and angular js embedded frontend. So everything running on weblogic server.
Now we are in the process of migrating from angular js to angular. Now angular is running on http://localhost:4200. So I have created a proxy for HTTP call

{
"/api": {
"target": " [http://127.0.01:7000"](http://127.0.01:7000%22),
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug",
"changeOrigin": true
}
}

And started server like so:
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json -o

server started on 4200 and creates proxy on http://127.0.01:7000/api

I have also created ssl proxy for HTTPS call
{
"/api": {
"target": "https://127.0.01:7001",
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug",
"changeOrigin": true
}
}

Also started server like so on different port
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.ssl.conf.json –-port 4400

server started on 4400 and creates proxy on https://127.0.01:7001/api

Now I make the first call to backend url http://127.0.01:7000/api/permission
It calls through as http://localhost:4200/api/permission

It goes through filter and does some processing then it checks if call is through http or https if not then asks to redirect to https://localhost:7001/api/permission with some status code.

So in angular inside interceptor I check for the status, if status is for redirect, I redirect the url to
https://127.0.01:7001/api/permission
using
window.location.href=”https://localhost:4400/api/permission”
don’t be confuse because it calls like https://localhost:4400 and concat with backend url which is /api/permission.
Angular folks must be aware of that.
But I get a 504 error gateway timeout on chrome dev tools console
On cmd where I have started the ng server I get this
Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/permission from localhost:4400 to https://127.0.01:7001 (ECONNRESET) (https ://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

I am dead sure it’s a SSL issue but I just don’t know how to fix this.
I have done a lot research on this. I am frustrated, I have spent more than enough time to find a solution for this. I cant basically move pass this till its converted from http to https because rest of the uri calls must be made on https.

I found a link
[How to send an HTTPS request from an Angular front-end to a server secured with a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371487/how-to-send-an-https-request-from-an-angular-front-end-to-a-server-secured-with/54372225#54372225)

I think solution number one made sense

1. Add the self-signed certificate to the trusted store on the server where the angular app runs. (But in your case u cant do this because u got no access to the gitpages trusted store.

But I cant say for sure.
Any help please. I would really appreciate that. I am pretty much stuck at this point.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I am a bit late to answer. But the exact answer to my problem was PKI which is mutual authentication configured on weblogic and the way its done is you need to deploy your angular app on weblogic to kick in mutual authentication. There are several videos out their on how to deploy angular app on weblogic if someone looking to learn as well as how to configure mutual authentication on weblogic. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Injectable()
export class httpsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log(req.url);

    const secureReq = req.clone({
      url: req.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
    });

    return next.handle(secureReq);
  }
}
```

you must create an interceptor and import it in the module inside provider,
providers: [
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true } ]

Comment: Shall I set this under if condition? like so: const secureReq;  if(error.status == redirectcode){ secureReq = req.clone({
      url: req.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
    });  }  because first request has to go through http localhost

Comment: Yes, maybe it works. But are you using localhost to make the requests? or was it just an example.  if it doesn't work, create an interceptor like this I gave you

Comment: Also Do I still need ssl proxy or just keep http://locahost:7000 proxy and keep everything on 4200?

Comment: actually its  localhost:4200 for angular and for backend proxy its http:// 
 127.0.01:7000 and https://  127.0.01:7001

Comment: if you are going to make a request with HTTPS, you need SSL. If you are trying to make a request from the front end with SSL it is not possible to make a request to a back end without SSL, both must have it. (I'm using google translator, sorry for any mistakes)

Comment: instead of using localhost, have you tried using the server's public ip?

Comment: For front end angular its only http localhost 4200. when I am making backend calls first call shall be on http which is going through proxy and after redirection every call should be on https call. Thats where the confusion starts. The second proxy i have created is on https which I started on port 7001 { "/api": { "target": "https://localhost:7001", "secure": false, "logLevel": "debug", "changeOrigin": true } } which will run on angular port 4400. Now I am not sure if the angular url also needs to be changed from http:// localhost 4200 to https:// localhost 4400 to make backend ssl calls.

Comment: why not do everything with SSL?

Comment: tried ip address(127.0.0.1) and just(localhost) for backend. It only works with http proxy not https proxy. Tried SSL for angular as well. Same result 504 Gateway timeout and on console Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/permission from localhost:4400 to https://127.0.01:7001 (ECONNRESET) (https ://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Comment: right, have you tried to use the ip of the server instead of the localhost and the IP (127.0.0.1) and use SSL (with the public ip)?

Comment: yes. SSL public ip not sure what that is.

Comment: public ip of the server you are hosting

Comment: I just tried that. Thats actually throwing 500. Thats even worse.